# Remove dynamic generated end of URL

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a Joomla 2.5 website with joomshopping and AceSEF extension component.

SEF URL generation works just fine except one  issue.

For some reason, there are dynamic parts generated in the end of the SEF URL, means i can not control this through AceSEF.

The URL that is not working is:

```
/projects?category_id=&label_id=&manufacturer_id=&page=&price_from=&price_to=&vendor_id=
```

I need to change this to: `/projects`

Answer (score 1):

You can override any URL in AceSEF by using adding a SEF URL to the REAL URL.

Follow these simple steps:

1. Login to the Administrator Panel in Joomla
2. Click > Components > AceSEF > URLS (Or paste `yoursite.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_acesef&controller=sefurls&task=view` into browser)
3. On the left side you have a filter box under SEF URL enter the URL that you want to change.
4. Once filtered simply click the REAL URL
5. Your be prompted with a popup modal that you can enter a SEF URL, simply add projects/ or anything you want to use.

If this doesn't solve the problem of new URLS being created then sadly the problem lays with the Joomshopping Extension for AceSEF, You're need to seek support from AceSEF if this is the case as your need a custom edit or they review their plugin and update the issue, AceSEF provide many support packages that you can purchase.

Comment: Its not a real url. The url seemingly gets generated like: "Real URL" --> "acesef URL" --> "dynamic added stuff" . There us a SEF url in aceSEF which points the "real URL" to /projects

Comment: Additionally to say i have tried to use the moved URL function too without success. Is there any htaccess redirect possible? ive tried wit h301 without success.

Comment: REAL URLS = Anything index.php?string, SEF URLS (Search Engine Friendly URLS) = /projects/ (Hence no string)

Comment: /projects/ is not a real url, its a sef url.

Comment: i never questioned that, pls reread. /projects/  was intended to be the SEF url, /projects also was set as SEF url  in aceSEF. The rest is added to the url dynamically, that is the big riddle.